# In the sentence "My house is down the street", which word does the adverb "down" modify?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, adverbs

> My house is down the street.

Does the adverb *down* modify *is*, or *street*?

Comment: _Up_ is not an adverb in this construction; it's a preposition, like _up_ or _on_, and its object is _the street_. Most English words can be many parts of speech, so calling anything an adverb (or a noun, or verb, or adjective, etc.) is of no use in understanding grammar or usage.

Comment: @John Lawler: haha - the mere fact that you could address OP's hypothetical usage of "up" (rather than his *actual* "down") just goes to show how meaningless it is to speak of either word "modifying" anything in this exact context. Granted, it would make a difference if you lived on a hill - but we happily use both forms even where the street is perfectly level.

Answer (score 7):

*Down* here is not an adverb but a preposition, heading the prepositional phrase *down the street*.

The PP as a whole acts as — well, now it gets tricky. The grammar I grew up with would have called it an *adverb of location* modifying *is*:

> Where is the house? *There*. It's down the street.

But the older I get the less I like that. I'm inclined to say that the PP acts as an *adjective of location* modifying (actually, “predicated of”) *house*:

> Which house? *That* house. The house down the street.

Which all goes to show how much more flexible the language is than the categories we use to describe it.

But in real life it's whatever your English teacher says it is.

Comment: Ah, I should have read this before I added the comment above, StoneyB. I agree with your analysis (keep getting older!) that there is no true adverbial behaviour here. I think one gets into trouble with mooting adjectival behaviour also: Is John here / home yet / down the road? John ran home / across the road. John died down the road. Though there are differences in adjectival - adverbial flavour, I tend to lump these as '_locative / directional_ (and some _temporal_) _expressions_'. dialnet.unirioja.es/descarga/articulo/1983827.pdf investigates the inadequacies of most classifications.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Where I come from, this use of what are normally attributive constituents is called *predicative*. So I would call it a predicative prepositional phrase. Similarly, *I came first* has a predicative adjective. This term is widely used.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following you. Prepositional phrases are rarely used in an attributive position (when they are compound adjectives anyway). _Down the road_ is syntactically replaceable by _home_ or _here_ in some expressions (John ran X; Is John X?) - the covering term _locative / directional expressions_ works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Neither.  *Down* in this situation is a *preposition*, not an adverb.  The complete phrase is "down the street".  You can tell it doesn't modify either of the two words because it can't be separated from them:

> My house is down.
>
> My house is the street.

Neither makes sense.

Comment: "down the street," however, is an adverbial prepositional phrase modifying "is"

Comment: @NateChandler - Yes, quite true.

Comment: I disagree. One really has to stretch the notion of modification (which admittedly some grammarians do) to allow 'down the street' to be a modifier of 'be / is' here. Surely a better analysis is one comparable to link-verb + complement: He is cold. He is here. He is down the street. The link-verb is a necessary grammatical device (admittedly showing tense); young children make do with _John here_ etc (tense _is_ now a difficulty). Intuitively, adverb(ial)s tell us something about the way the action of the verb is happening. Here / down the street tells us more about the house than any be-ing.

Answer (score 0):

Adverbs cannot ever be used with copulas, as the copula essentially has no 
meaning and can be omitted, as it is in Russian and AAVE.  A russian proverb:
"Sex without love -- work."  Usually the word "is" is used in the translation
to English.  Therefore the prepositional phrase is an adjective, as copulas 
are followed by a noun in the nominative, not the accusative, or by a 
descriptive adjective which directly modifies the subject of the verb, e.g., 
the sentence "John is green with envy and hates his brother now." could just 
as easily be "Green with envy, John hates his brother now.".  Green modifies
John.  Same deal with "down the street".

You cannot "be" swimmingly, but you sure can "get along" swimmingly.

So to answer the question, the old-fashion way I was taught:

"Down" is not an adverb, and it does not modify anything.  "Down the street" is 
a prepositional phrase used as an adjective, and it modifies "house".  For 
example, look at "upon", which is never an adverb.  My house is "upon the street"
yonder.  You can say someone sat "upon the witness seat", and that he's "going
down" and end the sentence right there, meaning he's going to prison because of
his crime, but you cannot say he's "sitting upon" unless you say upon what he is
sitting.  These phrases give the location, not destination, as in "going down to
the 7-Eleven", an adverbial prepositional phrase.  People speak of going "up to Denver", because it is
north of Santa Fe, New Mexico, but also "down to Denver", because it is at a low
altitude, only 5000 feet.  In French Canada, everywhere is "l`a-bas" = "down
there", and everything is "l`a", that is, "over there", even when immediately 
close at hand.  I understand the chicken lips would say "ici", that is "y" =
"there" plus "-ci" = here.  People also talk of going down to places that are 
less important, up to places that are more important, or just use "down" to mean
"over to".  In Chamisal, New Mexico, people go "into town" or "up town" meaning 
north to Taos, or "downtown" meaning the much bigger city of Santa Fe, which is
both south and larger and possessing a central area called "downtown".  Taos does
not have a downtown, because once you leave the central area, you are in open
fields.

Rivers are the exception.

No one goes down the Nile and ends up in Ethiopia, even if it is south of
Alexandria and reachable by water.

--Max Crane

Answer (score 0):

"down the street" is a preposition group that is typically used after verbs of movement as in

- He was slowly walking down the street. It is not so much a where or where-to indication but an indication of the way or direction.

Sometimes such preposition groups can be used after the linking verb to be as in

- Greenwich is down the river.

I think one has to supplement "Greenwich is at a point that you reach when you go down the river" to understand the development of this use.